# cascade = CascadeType.ALL doesn´t work on OneToOne relation

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-one

I have one problem with One to One relation.

I have one USER that has only one TEAM

User Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@Data @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor @Builder
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3233149207833106460L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "USERID")
    private Long id;
    
    ...
 
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    private Team team;

}
```

Team Entity

```
    

@Entity
@Table(name = "TEAM")
@Data @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor @Builder
public class Team implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3233149207833106460L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "TEAMID")
    private Long id;

...
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USERID")
    private User user;
    
    
}
```

This is the way I´m trying to create object.

```
    
        //create Team and add to User
        Team team = Team
                .builder()
                .value(TeamConstants.INITIAL_VALUE)
                .name(userDetailsForm.getUsername()+" "+TeamConstants.TEAM)
                .country(userDetailsForm.getUsername()+" "+TeamConstants.COUNTRY)
                .build();

        
        User user = User
                .builder()
                .username(userDetailsForm.getUsername())
                .password(this.passwordEncoder.encode(userDetailsForm.getPassword()))
                .email(userDetailsForm.getEmail())
                .registerDate(DateUtil.getNow())
                .role(userDetailsForm.getRole())
                .team(team)
                .build();
        
        team.setUser(user);
        
        this.userRepository.save(user);
```

And when I try to save user (and create automatically the son team), it gaves me the error

> Blockquote
> org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.soccermanager.business.entities.user.User.team -> com.soccermanager.business.entities.team.Team;

Any idea with the solution?

This is my first question here, I hope its correct.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please interact with Team entity then user will be change follow CascadeType

or you need add
`@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL) private Team team;` in User class.

Please try both and you can see the different. Hope this post answer can help with you

Comment: Thanks very much, it works now... The only stange thing is that mysql autogenerate ids are crossing.... If userid = 40, teamid = 41. They are not independient.

Comment: Solved autogenerate id problem using '@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)' Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should save your team entity before your user.
You should do as you do only if you are working in the same JPA Transaction unit. If not, it will not work and you get that exception.
Try adding `@Transactional` annotation on the method, with optional params like `propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED` and `readonly=false` because you are creating/updating objects here :

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
protected User saveTeamWithUser(UserDetailsForm form) {
    //    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.I tried that but still the same error.

Comment: @Override
 @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
 public User createUser(UserDetailsForm userDetailsForm) throws DuplicateInstanceException {

Comment: Did you try the start of my answer "You should save your team entity before your user" using your teamRepository and save your user after that ?

Comment: But... how can I save Team, if I have not created user first? Team needs userid value.

Comment: You can save them and after you make the relationship with an `addTeam(Team team)` method inside your User entity. and same in User, you can make a relationship with an `addUser(User user)` method inside your Team entity.

Comment: By default, relationships have an optional parameter which is set to true.

Comment: My Team table has one foreign key to user table. I think it would be better to create first user (father) and later team (son). Anyway, I thougth jpa did it automatically, I don´t understand why it´s not working.

Comment: If team is your father object, then save your user which is transient (not saved in your database so it does not have any id so hibernate can't make the relationship itself).